# Which are the cheapest supermarket chains in Cambodia?

Tags: budget, shopping, price, cambodia

I have landed in Cambodia yesterday so far I managed to go to Lucky's and for some goods their prices seem to be pretty ok, but for some prices are exorbitant (half loaf of bread for 2.45$ and 3.10$)

I have [asked this question for Thailand chains and it really helped me to save some bucks](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/85929/which-are-cheapest-thailand-supermarket-chains)...

Which of the following Cambodian supermarket chains would be considered 'cheap' (think ASDA or Walmart) and which ones 'expensive' (Marks & Spencer)

- Lucky Supermarket
- Aeon Supermarket
- Bayon Market
- Thai Huot, Thai Huot BKK1
- The Providore
- Super Duper
- Veggy’s
- Natural Garden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list, which [Move to Cambodia](http://www.movetocambodia.com/food/the-best-supermarkets-in-phnom-penh/) considers 'the ten best supermarkets in Phnom Penh,' are described in the blog:

> Phnom Penh’s supermarkets aren’t cheaper, of course, than shopping at a local market, but if you prefer your meats refrigerated, your prices fixed and access to imported products, you’ve got many options in Phnom Penh, and more are being added all of the time including organic options. This updated posts features the ten best supermarkets in Phnom Penh.

Some things are relative and items that are good value in one market may be overpriced in another, and relative in terms of opinion, but divided into your two groups: 'M&S' with a higher prices and 'ASDA' with those lower.

- *M&S-ish*: Lucky Supermarket, Aeon Supermarket, Natural Garden, The Providore, Super Duper
- *ASDA-ish*: Bayon Market, Thai Huot, Veggy’s, Natural Garden

As you recounted in your Thai experience, you found certain shops had what you wanted at fair prices. For a sense of what those should be, the Numbeo.com site offers a useful tool that compares the average cost of items to those in other countries, e.g., enabling you to [compare the costs of items in Phnom Penh to those in London](https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/compare_cities.jsp?country1=United%20Kingdom&country2=Cambodia&city1=London&city2=Phnom%20Penh&tracking=getDispatchComparison).

For staples, here are average prices in Phnom Penh, followed by that amount expressed in British Pounds, with the average cost in London in parentheses.

**Milk**, regular, 1 gallon:  **33741.42 CR** = 6.71 £ (3.42 £)
**Bread**, 1 pound:  **4977.77 CR** = 0.99 £ (0.91 £)
**Rice**, white, 1 pound:  **1609.13 CR** = 0.32 £ (0.61 £)
**Eggs**, dozen:  **6638.61 CR** = 1.32 £ (2.18 £)
 
**Local Cheese**, 1 pound:  **22728.95 CR** = 4.52 £ (2.86 £)
**Chicken Breasts**, 1 pound: **8298.26 CR** = 1.65 £ (3.02 £)
**Beef Round**, 1 pound: **20112.18 CR** = 4.00 £ (3.80 £)
**Apples**, 1 pound: **6539.07 CR** = 1.30 £ (0.88 £)
**Banana**, 1 pound: **1910.66 CR** = 0.38 £ (0.45 £)
**Oranges**, 1 pound: **5731.97 CR** = 1.14 £ (0.86 £)
**Tomato**, 1 pound: **2111.98 CR** = 0.42 £ (0.87 £)
**Potato**, 1 pound: **3268.54 CR** = 0.65 £ (0.55 £)
**Onion**, 1 pound: **1961.13 CR** = 0.39 £ (0.49 £)
**Lettuce**, 1 head: **2716.23 CR** = 0.54 £ (0.78 £)
**Water**, 1.5 liter bottle: **3268.54 CR** = 0.65 £ (0.88 £)
**Bottle of Wine**, Mid-Range: **40324.93 CR** = 8.02 £ (8.00 £)
**Domestic Beer**, 0.5 liter: **5482.32 CR** = 1.09 £ (1.70 £)
**Imported Beer**, 11.2 ounce: **6890.63 CR** = 1.37 £ (1.67 £)
**Pack of Cigarettes**, Marlboro: **6035.58 CR** = 1.20 £ (9.50 £)

Comment: It's worth noting that western staples and Cambodian staples are not the same thing. Cheese and bread and milk are more exotic in Cambodia. It doesn't have the huge western expat scene that Thailand has, or Thailand's middle class. The equivalent that Cambodia does have seems to be more Chinese than western. The more you can live on Cambodian staples the less expensive. Well unlike Thailand, Cambodia is full of bakeries but really only French-style white bread, which for many Europeans will be of limited appeal.